# How can you convert a Hermite surface to a Bezier surface for use in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, bezier, surface

I found a method to convert a Hermite curve into Bezier curve, but is there a similar method to convert a Hermite surface into a Bezier surface that I can use with OpenGL?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL just draws stuff. It's not a geometry library. You can use OpenGL evaluators to draw those bezier curves/patches you obtained, if using OpenGL<3. With OpenGL-3 and onward you'll have to implement bezier tesselation yourself, though it's easy enough, and can be done very well in a vertex or geometry shader.

Comment: thank u, actually i had to do this for an assignment and then to compare our result to surface made by using 'evaluator'.
i got the hint for conversion from www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBC07/HT04/handouts/HO-lecture9.pdf